# camera zooming messing with movement?

Tags: actionscript-3, camera

i have been looking into an effective way to simulate a camera in as3. everywhere i have read have basically told me the same thing; dont move the character, just move the stage around it.
ok, that works for simple things.  but what happens when you want to zoom in? simply inflating objects doesnt work, because distances fluctuate and movement values suddenly arent to scale.
is there an effective way to work around this? vcams (virtual cameras) seem like an easy alternative, but from my research, i cant afford that memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy solution is to just scale the entire instance of the game itself.

So, create an instance of the game's class, just like you normally would, and center it on the stage.
[image]

Then use scaleX and scaleY to make the instance of the game look bigger. The game will still behave like it should and you won't need to adjust the movement values or anything like that.

[image]

Comment: thanx for your response! i'll try to implement that